# ASP.NET MVC 4 preloader

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, preloader

Currently my app does an API call in global.asax's Session_Start method that fills a bunch of session variables. The problem is that this makes the application take a good 10 seconds to load for the first time.

I'd like to put some sort of "Loading..." preloader during this time, but I'm not sure how to do it or where to put it.

Comment: I'd highly recommend that you avoid doing API calls in `Session_Start`. What kind of API call are we talking? Could it be moved somewhere else?

Comment: I'm sure it could, but I'm not sure where. I'm pretty new to ASP.NET. I just need to be able to access the session variables from any page on the site.

Comment: The call itself just populates `DataSet ds`. I then do `DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0]` and use a foreach to add a bunch of session variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session_Start is triggered before user will be able to log in, is this possible that data you are fetching is the same in application scope? If yes move your code to Application_Start. If not it will be good to change your approach. Lazy loading - fetchdata only if needed, or use cache - if possible.

Comment: Thanks! For storing variables that I want to hold on to throughout the site, should I put them in `@Session["VariableName"]`?

Comment: If data is uniqe and different for each session than YES otherwise NO. Why? There is no need to copy the same data to each Session - not effective. You can try store the data in Global.asax as property (public static MyObject MyProperty {get; set;}) of Appliacation class.

Comment: Thank you! The data is unique and different for each session so I will keep using session variables.